# Editable multiple forms on a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) plugin to preform in place edit

This is the code I am using that I got from their [Doc](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#newrecord) page, it is supposed to be used for adding new records, But I want to use it to modify records)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   //init editables 
   $('.myeditable').editable({
      url: '/post',
      placement: 'right'
   });

   //make username required
   $('#new_username').editable();

   //automatically show next editable
   $('.myeditable').on('save.newuser', function(){
       var that = this;
       setTimeout(function() {
           $(that).closest('td').next().find('.myeditable').editable('show');
       }, 500);
   });

   //create new user
   $('#save-btn').click(function() {
       $('.myeditable').editable('submit', { 
           url: '/newuser', 
           ajaxOptions: {
               dataType: 'json' //assuming json response
           },           
           success: function(data, config) {
               if(data && data.id) {  //record created, response like {"id": 2}
                   //set pk
                   $(this).editable('option', 'pk', data.id);
                   //remove unsaved class
                   $(this).removeClass('editable-unsaved');
                   //show messages
                   var msg = 'New user created! Now editables submit individually.';
                   $('#msg').addClass('alert-success').removeClass('alert-error').html(msg).show();
                   $('#save-btn').hide(); 
                   $(this).off('save.newuser');                   
               } else if(data && data.errors){ 
                   //server-side validation error, response like {"errors": {"username": "username already exist"} }
                   config.error.call(this, data.errors);
               }               
           },
           error: function(errors) {
               var msg = '';
               if(errors && errors.responseText) { //ajax error, errors = xhr object
                   msg = errors.responseText;
               } else { //validation error (client-side or server-side)
                   $.each(errors, function(k, v) { msg += k+": "+v+"<br>"; });
               } 
               $('#msg').removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-error').html(msg).show();
           }
       });
   }); 

   //reset
   $('#reset-btn').click(function() {
       $('.myeditable').editable('setValue', null)
                       .editable('option', 'pk', null)
                       .removeClass('editable-unsaved');

       $('#save-btn').show();
       $('#msg').hide();                
   });
});
</script>
```

And this is the html

```
<tr>

      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" id="new_username" data-type="text" data-name="name" data-original-title="Enter name">adel</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" data-type="textarea" data-name="description" data-original-title="Enter Description"></a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" data-type="text" data-name="location" data-original-title="Enter Location"></a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" data-type="text" data-name="website" data-original-title="Enter Website"></a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" data-type="text" data-name="picture" data-original-title="Enter Picture"><img src=""></img></a></td>
      <td width="10%"><button id="save-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Ok</button><button id="reset-btn" class="btn btn-sm pull-right">Reset</button></td>

   </tr>

<tr>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" id="new_username" data-type="text" data-name="name" data-original-title="Enter name">sdqsd</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" data-type="textarea" data-name="description" data-original-title="Enter Description"></a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" data-type="text" data-name="location" data-original-title="Enter Location"></a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" data-type="text" data-name="website" data-original-title="Enter Website"></a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" data-type="text" data-name="picture" data-original-title="Enter Picture"><img src=""></img></a></td>
      <td width="10%"><button id="save-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Ok</button><button id="reset-btn" class="btn btn-sm pull-right">Reset</button></td>

   </tr>

<tr>

      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" id="new_username" data-type="text" data-name="name" data-original-title="Enter name">dzadz</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" data-type="textarea" data-name="description" data-original-title="Enter Description">from me with love</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" data-type="text" data-name="location" data-original-title="Enter Location">anywhere</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" data-type="text" data-name="website" data-original-title="Enter Website">http://justawebsite.com</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="myeditable" data-type="text" data-name="picture" data-original-title="Enter Picture"><img src=""></img></a></td>
      <td width="10%"><button id="save-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Ok</button><button id="reset-btn" class="btn btn-sm pull-right">Reset</button></td>
   </tr>
```

Now everything works fine, Except if I edit one of the 2 first rows and hit Ok It will send the details of the last form `http://justawebsite.com` and sometimes it doesn't send anything, It is really messed up and I spent hours reading te documentation but I couldn't figure out the problem

Comment: First of all, you've got different elements with the same id... Fix that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you've got different elements with the same id, so the selectors won't work (id must be unique). Put them as class instead:

```
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="myeditable new_username" data-type="text" data-name="name" data-original-title="Enter name">adel</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="myeditable description" data-type="textarea" data-name="description" data-original-title="Enter Description"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="myeditable location" data-type="text" data-name="location" data-original-title="Enter Location"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="myeditable website" data-type="text" data-name="website" data-original-title="Enter Website"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="myeditable picture" data-type="text" data-name="picture" data-original-title="Enter Picture">
        <img src="" />
      </a>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm save-btn">Ok</button>
      <button class="btn btn-sm pull-right reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Here's a fiddle to get you started https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/k2of9xor/1/

On there, you'll see that I've selected the editable elements you want to submit.

```
$('.save-btn').click(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var allEditables = that.parents("tr").find(".myeditable"); // all ".myeditable" elements in the same "tr" as the ".save-btn" that was clicked on
    allEditables.each(function() {
        // here I've kept your code because I don't know what happens in your file, but maybe you need a bulk action
      $(this).editable('submit', { 
         ...
```

I don't know how your PHP file works, so don't know how you save your user and if you need to submit all fields at once or not. If so, you'll have to modify my answer a bit.

Comment: It doesn't work , Say that I want to rewrite the whole thing how can I do it ?

Comment: I did say 'to get you started' ;) Have you checked the fiddle? In your JS you need to make sure the selectors are correct. Add console.log to check the right element is being selected, and debug from there. Good luck :)

Comment: @jokoliptos I've updated my answer and fiddle. Do check and make the correct changes. I've only just corrected the field selection part. You need to see what you do when you submit or provide your PHP code if you want further help

Comment: Thank you , I was banging my head on the wall trying to fix it, I don't have a lot of experience with js , Only I needed to send all the elements of a single tr at once instead of applying for each on them, But don't worry I'll finish it with myself from now ,you've been a great help

Comment: @jokoliptos No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refreshing it afterwards?

For me i noticed, that as soon as it was refreshed i got the result that i have been expecting, but only for one of them. However, i couldn't solve the problem yet.
Please let me know what kind of result you get.

Otherwise try debugging...disable one of the first rows and try it again..

Comment: Here is what happen
If I edit the first row and hit enter it will send the details of the last row,When I do that I can't submit the second row until I refresh , If the user need to refresh the page to edit another record it lose the meaning of using this plugin

Comment: Okay. What happens if you edit the first and the third one?

Comment: It doesn't work , Say that I want to rewrite the whole thing how can I do it ?

Comment: Read the answer of VirginieLGB she is describing a proper solution for this. I had the issue that, i was saving fore- and lastname at the same time and only the forename was saved dynamically..that is why i was asking what happens if you refresh it again or try first and third one..